# Is $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ diagonalizable if and only if $V$ = null($T) \, \oplus$ range($T$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is an exercise in my book that states the following: "Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is diagonalizable. Then $V = null(T) \oplus range(T)$."

I am wondering if the statement can go the other way? I can't think of any counter examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, $$\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$ is not diagonalizable, but its range is $\mathbb F^2$ (where $\mathbb F$ is the field we're working over) and its null space is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Can't believe I missed this